# Ассемблер, стек и строки.

Tags: ассемблер, linux

Здраствуйте, уважаемые программисты.
Сейчас я осваиваю ассемблер (а конкртено AT&T синтаксис под системой Ubuntu 10.10), и у меня возник вопрос, почему этот код работает?

```
.data  
msg:  
 .string "Hello, world!\n"  
.text  
.globl main  
main:  
 pushl $msg #вот здесь-то у меня и возникает вопрос  
 call printf  
 addl $4, %esp
```

Так вот, вопрос в том, почему я заталкиваю на стек 4 байта, в то время, когда мое сообщение занимает больше байт?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ты в стек заталкиваешь не слово, а адрес по которому расположена метка msg. Размер данных, помещаемых в стек определяется суффиксом l(push) - двойное слово, 4 байта.
Вот хорошая [статья](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2_Linux_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_C#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.8B_.D0.B0.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B), сам учусь по ней )

Comment: все равно немного не понимаю, ведь я заталкиваю ссылку на первый элемент на 'H', но размер ссылки равен размеру объекта, на который он ссылается(в Си во всяком случае так, а я думаю, что ссылка-она и в Африке ссылка)

Comment: Размер указателя (ссылка - это из С++) не всегда равен размеру объекта, на который он указывает. Он машинозависим и по сути представляет собой беззнаковый целочисленный тип. В х32 он имеет размер 4 байта, в х86_64  - 8 байт. А указывать может на начало раздела памяти, содержащий что угодно, любой тип данных любого размера.

Comment: >размер ссылки равен размеру объекта
Речь идет не о ссылке а об указателе или адресе. А сказать что размер адреса равен размеру объекта, это то же самое что сказать что размер адреса дома равен размеру самого дома:) Применительно к памяти, адрес - это просто номер ячейки, с которой начинается объект. Какого бы размера ни был объект, номер ячейки все равно будет 32-(или 64-)битным целым числом.

Comment: спасибо всем за помощь